# Prefer &str over String? Is it always the case?

Tags: string, rust

The documentation of Rust suggests to use &str whenever it's possible and only when it's not, use String. Is it always the case? For example, I'm building the client for REST API of a web-service and I have an entity:

```
struct User {
  id: &str // or String?
  name: &str // or String?
  //......
}
```

So is it better to use `&str` or `String` in general and in this particular case?

Comment: I recommend you read [this](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/).

Comment: @WindorC, I recommend you to read my post.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: Your post does not contain anywhere enough information for us to advise you. The advice in the documentation is sound: *whenever possible*; but of course it means that you (the developer) needs to understand what is possible and what it hinges upon. In this case, it hinges on ownership, and without any precision as to the ownership of what `&str` would point to there just is no way to answer the question for your particular case, only generic advices can be given.

Comment: @MatthieuM, why haven't you posted that as the answer?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: Because I am waiting for a question update precising how `User` is used to see whether a `String` or a `&str` is best in this particular case.

Comment: @MatthieuM. you can wait for however long you wish while others just answer the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Rust everything related to a decision whether to use a reference or not stems from the basic concepts of ownership and borrowing and their applications. When you design your data structures, there is no clean rule: it wholly depends on your exact use case.

For example, if your data structure is intended to provide a view into some other data structure (like iterators do), then it makes sense to use references and slices as its fields. If, on the other hand, your structure is a DTO, it is more natural to make it own all of its data.

I believe that a suggestion to use `&str` where possible is more applicable to function definitions, and in this case it indeed is natural: if you make your functions accept `&str` instead of `String`, their caller will be able to use them easily and with no cost if they have either `String` or `&str`; on the other hand, if your functions accept `String`s, then if their caller has `&str`, they will be forced to allocate a new `String`, and even if they have `String` but don't want to give up ownership, they still would need to clone it.

But of course there are exceptions: sometimes you do want to transfer ownership inside a function. Some data structures and traits, like `Option` or `Reader`, provide an ability to turn an owned variant to a borrowed one (`Option::as_ref()` and `Reader::by_ref()`), which are sometimes useful. There is also a [`Cow`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) type which kind of "abstracts" over ownership, allowing you to pass a borrowed value which will be cloned if necessary. Sometimes there is a trait like [`BytesContainer`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/trait.BytesContainer.html) which abstracts over various types, owning as well as borrowing, and which allows the caller to pass values of different types.

What I wanted to stress, again, is that there is no fixed rule, and it wholly depends on concrete task you're working on. You should use common sense and ownership/borrowing concepts when you architect your data structures.

In your particular case whether to use `String` or `&str` depends on what you will actually do with `User` objects - just "REST API client" is unfortunately too vague. It depends on your architecture. If these objects are used *solely* to perform an HTTP request, but the data is actually stored in some other source, then you would likely want to use `&str`s. If, on the other hand, `User` objects are used across your entire program, then it makes sense to make them own the data with `String`s.